# Linking Error between matlab R2013a and MS VC++ 2013

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, lnk2019, mixed-programming

I am writing a BCI game application in VC++ and require to implement Common Spatial Pattern Filtering (CSP) for feature extraction. Due to the hefty coding involved, I prefer to use an existing CSP Matlab function that I have. I followed the steps as given in [here](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2013/12/matlabc-mixed-programming-call-matlab.html). However, I am getting the following Link error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetScalar referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxDestroyArray referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxCreateDoubleScalar referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engEvalString referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engOpen referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engClose referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engGetVariable referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engPutVariable referenced in function _main
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engOutputBuffer referenced in function _main
1>D:\Test4\Debug\Test4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Could anyone please help me fix the problem? Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you instal the MCR (_Matlab Compiler Runtime_) on the same machine you run VC++ ?

Comment: I have both, MS VC++ and Matlab 2013a on the same PC.

Comment: ok, but i think you also need the MCR installed anyway.

Comment: What's the build target of your project? x64 or x86? Make sure you set the proper Matlab library path of different platforms.

Comment: @Hoki, I installed MCR too, but no luck.

Comment: @herohuyongtao : I know I have VC++ 2013 installed on Win7 (64-bit). I have set the Matlab library path as mentioned on your blog. Could you kindly tell me what and where exactly should I check to help you figure out the problem? Thnx

Comment: @Adee_lib Try to add `MATLAB-path\R2013a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft` to the library directories even you're building a Win32 project. Also add `libmx.lib libeng.lib` to the `Input` libraries.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I did as you mentioned, but no luck. I have emailed you screenshots of my settings. Plz check and hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the [referred post](http://blog-ythu.github.io/2013/12/27/mixed-programming-call-MATLAB-directly/), you have to keep the platforms consistent:

> **The platforms of MATLAB and VC++ compile platform must be the same**, i.e. Win32/x86 VC++ compile platform can only use x86 MATLAB and x64 VC++ compile platform can only use x64 MATLAB.

You're using MATLAB x64, thus you have to build your VC project in x64 too.